# Identifying the persons who delivered changesets to RTC, in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, rtc, rational-team-concert

Thanks for looking into my concern.

We are implementing CI with Rational Team Concert(RTC) and Jenkins. As part of this, I want to send the build notifications only to the persons delivered changesets to RTC.

Could you please help me with approaches to filter the person names who delivered changesets.

Regards,
R Dama

Answer (score 2):

See ***Post-Build actions***

→ ***E-mail Notification*** → ☑ *Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build* → [image] → ... *[Jenkins Mailer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mailer)*:

> - **Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build:** if checked, the notification e-mail will be sent to individuals who have committed changes for the broken build (by assuming that those changes broke the build).
>
>   If e-mail addresses are also specified in the recipient list, then both the individuals as well as the specified addresses get the notification e-mail. If the recipient list is empty, then only the individuals will receive e-mails.

or

→ ***Editable Email Notification*** → *Triggers* → ***Add Trigger*** → ***Always*** → *Send To* → ***Add*** → ***Developers*** → [image] → ... *[Jenkins Mailer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)*:

> Sends email to all the people who caused a change in the change set.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
My concern here is how to capture the name of person delivered changes to a stream in RTC.

Comment: @RDama I'm not familiar with RTC's terminology. What is a "_stream_" there? You just asked for "_the persons who delivered changesets_".

Comment: Stream is similar to a project in git. I want to get the names of developers whoever checkin's/commits the changes to a stream.

Comment: @RDama I am familiar with Git. From a technical POV you have repository, index and workspace there to which you can add, commit, checkout, etc. A project is just an organizational collection of one or more repos not a technical one.

Comment: Yes, Stream is identical to a repository

Comment: @RDama Well, did you try the **Editable Email Notification** then?

Comment: Thanks for helping me.
I tried the editable email notification and i did use a jelly script to print changesets delivered to a stream/repo. 
It is not even printing changesets.

I believe this is completely related to RTC and RTC plugin for Jenkins.